# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find button class="btn btn--highlight ng-binding"

Tags: selenium, button, capybara

I am testing this page that I have to fill up a form and only when all fields are filled and valid, the button is enabled to click, however, when trying to find the button to click I always get the message that capybara was unable to find the button or element or however I try to find it. The button does not have a name or an id.

I tried everything I found online but nothing seems to work. This is the code of the button when I inspect it on the browser:

```html
<div class="button-set terms ng-scope">
  <button class="btn btn--highlight ng-binding" ng-disabled="shippingAddressForm.$invalid || (!shop.useSameAddress &amp;&amp; billingAddressForm.$invalid) || view.loading" ng-class="{ disabled: shippingAddressForm.$invalid || (!shop.useSameAddress &amp;&amp; billingAddressForm.$invalid),
  loading: view.loading }" ng-click="shop.updateBothAddresses(view.shippingAddressModel, view.billingAddressModel)" style="">
    " Continuar "
    <span class="spinner"></span>
</button>
```

But I always get the error that whatever I try to find, it doesn't find.

Comment: Show the code you've tried to use to find it - along with the exact errors

Comment: **CODE:** `@browser.click_button(' Continuar ')`                                      
**ERROR:** `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find button " Continuar "`                                 
**CODE:** `@browser.find(:xpath, '//button[@class="btn.btn--highlight.ng-binding"]')`.                                      
**ERROR:** `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "//button[@class=\"btn.btn--highlight.ng-binding\"]"`.

Comment: Thanks - in the future, you should update the question with requested code rather than adding it in the comments so that it's easier for everyone to find/read.

Comment: Also, **CODE:** @browser.click_on(' Continuar ', :visible => false)
**ERROR:** Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find link or button " Continuar "

Comment: As stated in my answer the leading and trailing spaces in ' Continuar ' will not work - also you can't interact with a non-visible button so passing `visible: false` is counter productive

Answer (score 0):

Your initial attempt `click_button(' Continuar ')` doesn't work because Capybara generally normalizes text content using the XPath function `normalize-space` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space - when comparing it, so leading and trailing spaces would be stripped.  Try

```
click_button('Continuar')
```

Your second attempt `find(:xpath, '//button[@class="btn.btn--highlight.ng-binding"]')` doesn't work because you're mixing XPath and CSS syntax.  To find the button without using the text using XPath you could have done

```
# Note the leading . on the XPath selector - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap
find(:xpath, './/button[@class="btn btn--highlight ng-binding"]').click # in XPath it's just the attribute value - there is no . shortcut for classes
```

or with CSS

```
find(:css, 'button.btn.btn--highlight.ng-binding').click # the first argument :css is optional if Capybara.default_selector has the default value of :css
```

or using Capybara button finder

```
find_button(class: %w(btn btn--highlight ng-binding)).click # or
click_button(class: %w(btn btn--highlight ng-binding))
```

Comment: Tried all this ways but none of them worked.. please see the results I got:
**1.** click_button('Continuar') **error:** Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find button "Continuar"
**2.** find(:xpath, './/button[@class="btn btn--highlight ng-binding"]').click **error:** Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath ".//button[@class=\"btn btn--highlight ng-binding\"]"
**3.** find_button(class: %w(btn btn--highlight ng-binding)).click **error:** Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find button nil with classes [btn,btn--highlight,ng-binding].
And thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @MarianaFurini Then it sounds like that button isn't actually on the page, or isn't visible on the page.  Have you checked `page.html` to see what the actual html is and/or `page.save_and_open_screenshot` to see the actual current state of the page.

Comment: seems like there's nothing related to this button on the actual html.. but when I try this: @browser.assert_text('Continuar',:minimum => 1) it finds the text "Continuar"... idk whats happening.

Comment: I've also tried the option "visible" on the previous attempts and it did not work either.

Comment: @MarianaFurini Sounds like the text may be somewhere else on the page - without the full html to look at it's impossible to say.

Comment: @MarianaFurini  You can't interact with non-visible elements, so passing any version of `visible` to the finders/actions makes no sense, but I guess it does prove that the button isn't even hidden on the page -- you're just not on the page you think you are.

Comment: it makes sense, I will try to investigate the code some more and will update here